# How can isolve Mysql Error: Code: 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g

I tried to run the following query to select all of the lines respecting the join criteria, then adds all the rows in the table "client" and the table "commande" that were rejected because they did not meet the join criteria.

**Query**:`SELECT * FROM CLIENT c  FULL JOIN  commande com  ON c.id_client=com.id_client`

**Error**:Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL JOIN  commande com  on c.`id_client`=com.`id_client`
 LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL unfortunately does not support `FULL JOIN`.  You can achieve the same results with a `UNION` and an `OUTER JOIN` though:

```
SELECT c.*, com.* 
FROM CLIENT c 
    LEFT JOIN commande com ON c.id_client=com.id_client
UNION 
SELECT c.*, com.* 
FROM commande com
    LEFT JOIN CLIENT c  ON com.id_client=c.id_client
```

- [Simplified SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d9a6/4)

Also, consider defining your fields being returned versus returning all.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `full outer join` or `full inner join`

Answer (score 0):

try USING:

```
SELECT * FROM `CLIENT` FULL JOIN commande com USING (id_client) […];
```